# Pick image from gallery and send to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, iphone

How to add images from gallery and send that images from **MasterViewController** to **DetailViewController** using **Segue**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial for image picker:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_iOS_7_Camera_and_Photo_Library

After opening it the way you wanted, you need to call your segue in this delegate method for UIImagePicker delegate:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:
(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
     _image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
}
```

And in your prepareForSeague:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:_image];
    }
}
```

Of course you need to make proper connections for segue inside storyboard. But I guess what you want is the big picture of things need to be done.

I hope it helps!

Comment: @ P. Sami , i worked what u suggest, but i am getting 'reason: -[UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e3a6e0' exception

Comment: @GouthamKumar Have you added the segue in the storyboard? This usually indicates that there's no such segue!